# How to find the module with the conflicting requirement?

Tags: python, plone, buildout

I got an error about when running buildout:

```
Installing instance.
The version, 1.4.4, is not consistent with the requirement, 'plone.app.jquery>1.6'.
While:
  Installing instance.
Error: Bad version 1.4.4
```

I suppose that there is a module with the 'plone.app.jquery>1.6'. How can I find it to pindown it? Is there a command to do it? This is a common problem that I have when setting the eggs versions in a buildout.

This question is general. Suppose that I eggs A and B requires egg C, but with incompatible versions. As the code above, I got an error message about C, but not a message about A and B, that are the source of the incompatibility.

Comment: I use google. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.jquery/1.7.2

Comment: I solved the example problem, but my question is general. Is there a better tool than Google to solve module conflicts?

Comment: Try this `grep -RnHoi --include="requires.txt" "plone.app.jquery" ./eggs/*`